# Node js + CouchBase Lite + CouchBase Server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I have done a sample application using Couchbase Server with Node js.
But I want use Node js + CouchBase Lite + CouchBase Server (or) Angularjs + CouchBase Lite + CouchBase Server. Can any one please provide any reference links or documentations. 
I've googled a lot but i haven't found any solution.

Comment: i would take a look at the documentation

Comment: Have a look in the Couchbase blogs.  For example: https://blog.couchbase.com/node-js-swagger-monitor-document-changes-couchbase-mobile/

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're trying to develop. Just for clarification, Couchbase Lite is part of [Couchbase Mobile](https://www.couchbase.com/products/mobile) solution that represents a set of components allowing the offline management of local databases which can be "synchronized" with a Couchbase Server node or cluster. Hence, it only makes sense to use Couchbase Lite if you are developing a mobile app with local storage. If case you are developing a web site with in-browser client-side database, you can just use [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/), just like Couchbase's predecessor [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) did.

The mobile solution, however, gas important advantages, such as user authentication/security, done through Sync Gateway server. There users can have their own passwords and share different parts of the same database through channels.

Also note that using Node js in server-side is not preferable, since Native APIs from Couchbase Lite solution and Couchbase Server are not available in JavaScript/Typescript. Yet, you may use Note js to communicate with [Sync Gateway REST API](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/references/sync-gateway/rest-api/index.html) and [Couchbase Server REST API](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/rest-api/rest-intro.html).

Check existing solutions in [Couchbase Labs](https://github.com/couchbaselabs) repo and [Couchbase Blogs](https://blog.couchbase.com/). This one may be of interest:

- [Using Couchbase Mobile in a Web Application with only Angular 2 and PouchDB](https://blog.couchbase.com/using-couchbase-mobile-in-a-web-application-with-only-angular-2-and-pouchdb/)